# How to access and edit HTML Wordpress code?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a project for my studies, building a website with WordPress. The code needs to pass the W3C HTML & CSS check and here arrives my problem. I get tons of errors and warnings, and I don't know how I can edit the code and fix them.

[image]

### #1

I have tried the *Appearance* -> *Editor* thing, but I only have access to `style.css`, `functions.php` and `wpml-config.xml`. Plus, I don't have the rest of the CSS code, only what I wrote. (I'm using a child theme)

[image]

### #2

I tried with the Chrome console to locate the mistakes by copy/pasting the code, but the Chrome console says it is on a different line from what W3C tells me. I sometimes don't even find it.

[image]

### #3

So I tried to download the site files with FTP, but there is nothing written in `index.php` and other documents unlike what is shown on the Chrome console.

[image]

### #4

My question is pretty simple, how can I access the PHP/HTML/CSS code of my website, and modify it?

Comment: This may be a better question for https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The answer of hungerstar is all right, as i cant answer as comment i will answer here, see it more as an comment to the other answer. Now you found your theme folder, you are Ready to get rid of the W3 Errors, and as told by hungerstar you Do it in the child Theme. But if you search for a long string you will fast realize you wont find it in the theme files, thats because its not pure HTML, there is also a lot of PHP (for example to get the Theme Options you can set in WordPress Dashboard) the best way is to find some classes or ids of the elements in the HTML. I use Sublime Text there you can

Answer (score 0):

1. This is not where you need to be, you should edit local files.
2. When you inspect a page with Dev Tools, you are seeing the *live* DOM. Which is a representation of the HTML you sent the browser along with any modification that JavaScript has made to the DOM. The W3C checker won't see content added/changed by JavaScript. You will need to validate that separately.
3. Your site is built with a WordPress Theme. Theme files are located at `/wp-content/themes/[theme name]`. The files that are in the theme folder that your site is using might look something like the [Twenty Nineteen Theme](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen).
4. You've already got the files (via FTP), you just need to look in the right place (see #3).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using The-7 theme, and I want to edit the child theme. I followed your instructions on 3. , here is a screenshot of what I got : https://imgur.com/QYW0eVZ. So do I need to modify directly the theme files (and not the child theme) ?

Comment: It has been a while since I've done a child theme, but whatever parent theme files have the offending markup issues would need to be copied to the child theme and modified there. If someone with some current child theming experience can confirm this that would be great!

Comment: Don't edit the parent theme if it is not yours or plan to update the theme in the future, your changes will go bye bye.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. If I get you right I need to copy the theme files I want to modify in the child theme folder and modify them there with the code editor in Wordpress ?

Comment: That's correct, but I would edit them locally vs the editor in WordPress.